# I am developing RESTful app using Spring. I want to handle case when in POST request body has wrong data type

Tags: spring, web-services

I am using spring boot making web services and one of them taking object from :

```
public class GroupRouteRequestDTO {
    private Long groupID;
    private String userToken;
    private Long pageIndex; 

    private Long pageSize;
    private String search;
    }
```

class

in postman I make request with body

```
{
    "groupID":"11AA",
    "userToken": "9a",
    "pageIndex":0,
    "pageSize":12,
    "search":"A"

}
```

I get

```
{
    "timestamp": 1557340656686,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Long from String \"11AA\": not a valid Long value\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1226796e; line: 2, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.ntgclarity.ngnts.datatransferobject.GroupRouteRequestDTO[\"groupID\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Long from String \"11AA\": not a valid Long value\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1226796e; line: 2, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.ntgclarity.ngnts.datatransferobject.GroupRouteRequestDTO[\"groupID\"])",
    "path": "/toDoList/Employee"
}
```

this response from postman

And the web service is

```
@PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/Employee")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ToDoList_Access')")
    public Object getEmployeesRoutList(@Valid @RequestBody GroupRouteRequestDTO groupRouteRequest,HttpServletRequest request)
            throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return toDoListService.getEmployeesRoutList(groupRouteRequest,request);
    }
```

Question : can I make customize error msg from the web service to handle when the body of the request has wrong datatype?

Comment: I know , i need to make specific error msg to handle such errors

Comment: take a look at this Post it very helpfull https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

Comment: have a look at this post. https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by adding this method in controller class

````
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> MessageNotReadableException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,HttpServletResponse response){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Bad Request Please Check Your Inputs",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }```
````

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bean Validation. Refer [link](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)

For eg :

```
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

    public class User {

        @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
        private String name;

        @AssertTrue
        private boolean working;

        @Size(min = 10, max = 200, message 
          = "About Me must be between 10 and 200 characters")
        private String aboutMe;

        @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
        @Max(value = 150, message = "Age should not be greater than 150")
        private int age;

        @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
        private String email;

        // standard setters and getters 
    }
```

Comment: For custom validator refer https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-validator

Comment: No you cannot in this case, as it fails before that.